# What is the difference between profile and pattern in Prosite?

Tags: proteins, prosite

I found a definition:
"A pattern is thus a qualitative description of a motif in terms of amino acid sequence. The concept of a profile extends this concept, allowing a quantitative description of a motif, by assigning probabilities to the occurrence of a particular amino acid at each position of a motif."

This is example of profile in prosite

```
Hits for all PROSITE (release 2022_04) motifs on sequence P98073 [UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot]:
Example of profile
PS50024   SEA   SEA domain profile :
54 - 169:   score = 32.979
QSHEARATFKITsGVTYNPNLQDKLSVDFKVLAFDLQQMIDEIFLSSNLKNEYKNSRVLQ
FEN--GSIIVVFDLFFAQWVSD--ENVKEELIQGLEANKssQLVTFHIDLNSVDILDKLT

This is example of pattern in Prosite
PS01209   LDLRA_1   LDL-receptor class A (LDLRA) domain signature :
197 - 221:     [confidence level: (0)]  CIkadlf.CDgevNCpdgsDEDnkm..C
```

1. What is the difference in that case? So in profile I have probabilities (in definition I have "profile extends this concept, allowing a quantitative description of a motif, by assigning probabilities to the occurrence of a particular amino acid". I don't see any probabilities in that sequence.
2. What does it mean "-" in profiles? Maybe any aminoacid or gap?
3. Why I have sometimes lowercase letter and uppercase letter in profile and pattern? I don't get it. It's a probability?
4. What is more important profile or pattern?

Comment: Hi @MrMorgotheron and welcome. From my point of view its a good question, but a few too many questions, albeit I could be wrong. The "-" definitely means an indel, so you can remove that question to help focus the question more.

Comment: I think this was already answered on a different SE site: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46751/difference-between-motifs-domains-patterns-signatures-and-profiles

Comment: This publication explains it nicely: https://academic.oup.com/bib/article/3/3/265/239712?login=false